# How can determine path for saveAs()Function javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, path, save-as

**Q1:** How can determine path for saveAs()Function javascript ?

I wanna after downloaded file I wanna select path such as

C:\Users\file-\projectName\src\assets\i18n\en.json

```
const blob = new Blob([data], {type : 'application/json'});
saveAs( blob , 'en.json');
```

**Q2:** How can I  save data in same file after download  ?
such as

```
saveAs( blob , 'en.json');// new file
save( blob , 'en.json'); // same file
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't. The file path will always be set to the assigned downloads folder in your browser settings.
2. Also not possible, if you try to overwrite a file it will automatically rename the new one to avoid overwriting.